# How to redirect to https only if certain string appears in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I want to redirect all traffic to my site to https but the prospect is kind of scary and I want to test the redirect. I will eventually do this:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.example.com https://www.example.com
```

but I want to test it first. What is the best way to only redirect if a string for example REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS is present, so for example www.example.com?a=REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS(.*)$ [WHAT GOES HERE?] [L,R=301]
```

Is there a way to do this in a subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)a=REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}? [NE,L,R=301]
```

If it's only for one subdirectory, place this htaccess in the directory.